# How do I lay out images next to each other in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm downloading a set of images and displaying them side by side in a horizontally scrollable `UiScrollView`.

On Android, I have a `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView` with the appropriate gravity set. As images are downloaded, they are added to the layout and display appropriately - in the correct proportions, stretching the parent view to accommodate them.

On iOS I'm having a harder time. I'm using an [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) to load the images, and this works fine. The problem is I have to initialise each view with its bounds, before I know what they will be.

```
for(NSString* url in self.imageURLs){
    AsyncImageView *iView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageScroller.frame];
    [iView showActivityIndicator];
    [iView setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self.imageScroller addSubview:iView];
}
```

This doesn't work - all the images are loaded on top of one another, and are stretched out of proportion to fit the frame.

Is there an easy way to have 'gravity' or 'float' like layout in iOS? If not, how should I be laying out my images?

**EDIT**

Just to be clear: These images have different aspect ratios, so I can't know their dimensions until they have loaded.

Here's my Android layout

[image]

Comment: You could... set the frames manually for each image, use auto layout, use a tableview, use a collection view, use a UIPageViewController, other.

Comment: Could you explain one of these? Coming from Android, the iOS documentation can be completely impenetrable.

Comment: If you can life with support iOS 6+ only you should really check out [`UICollectionView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html). This is a `UI` component which can do exactly what you want.

Comment: @rckoenes I am targeting only iOS 6+, I'll take a look.

Comment: Please show an image of the desired layout (show your android screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set position(frame) of each iView manually.
For example for vertical placement:

```
CGFloat y = 0;
for(NSString* url in self.imageURLs){
    CGRect frame = self.imageScroller.bounds;
    frame.origin.y = y;
    y = y + frame.size.height;
    AsyncImageView *iView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [iView showActivityIndicator];
    [iView setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self.imageScroller addSubview:iView];
}
```

Also at the and of this you should increase your imageScroller content size to able to scroll:

```
self.imageScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(y, self.imageScroller.frame.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGRect currentFrame = self.imageScroller.bounds;
for(NSString* url in self.imageURLs){
    AsyncImageView *iView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:currentFrame];
    [iView showActivityIndicator];
    [iView setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self.imageScroller addSubview:iView];
    currentFrame.origin.x += current.frame.size.width; // that is if you put them next to each other horizontally, otherwise use origin.y and size.height
}
```

Also remember to set the contentSize of imageScroller if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the easiest way of doing this is just to calculate and set the frame for each image.

```
int i = 0;

float width = self.imageScroller.frame.size.width;
float height = self.imageScroller.frame.size.height;
float y = 0;

for(NSString* url in self.imageURLs){
    ++i;

    float x = i * width;

    AsyncImageView *iView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [iView showActivityIndicator];
    [iView setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self.imageScroller addSubview:iView];
}
```

However, this will have problems when you want to load a large number of images.

The best way to do this is to use a UIPageViewController. See somewhere like here... http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3120

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was simplest to do correctly by adding the data to the ajax payload:

```
CGRect currentFrame = self.imageScroller.bounds;
CGFloat currentX = self.imageScroller.bounds.origin.x;
for(NSDictionary* snap in self.imageURLs){
    NSNumber *iWidth = [snap objectForKey:@"width"];
    NSNumber *iHeight = [snap objectForKey:@"height"];
    CGFloat width = [iWidth floatValue] * currentFrame.size.height / [iHeight floatValue];
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(currentX, currentFrame.origin.y, width, currentFrame.size.height);
    AsyncImageView *iView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    [iView showActivityIndicator];
    [iView setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[snap objectForKey:@"url"]]];
    [self.imageScroller addSubview:iView];
    currentX += width;
}
self.imageScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX,currentFrame.origin.y);
```